# which is better, dynamic binding or interface class when implementing a callback interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, callback, std-function

In my case, I have to give a callback interface, there're 2 solutions:

case 1, interface class

```cpp
class interface {
public:
    virtual void callback(param_t params);
};
```

case 2:

```cpp
class dynamic_binding_interface {
public:
    std::function<void(param_t params)> callback;
};
```

what I'm worried about case 2 is:

1. in my case, I don't need to change the implementation of `callback`, so it's acctually one-time bind
2. it could be difficult to debug, since `std::function` cannot hold param names

the point is I'm worried about case 1 is:

1. complicated inheritance in the future
2. I must create a new class to implement `interface` each time

so, any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: Each have advantages and disadvantages, so it depends on the case.

Comment: By using `std::function` you generate a lot overhead. That is needed if you would also pass data within your callback itself but not needed of you simply want to call something without bound parms. In this case a pointer is more efficient. It depends on your needs! BTW: If you know at compile time your callback, you also can use a MIXIN.

Comment: @Klaus `std::function` means the callback could be implemented in a complicated way such as `lambda` , class member function etc.

Comment: Quite clear, if the overhead is ok for you. And even a non capturing lambda can be implicit converted to pointer to function. As long your "callable objects" do not need to keep data, you don't need the overhead. Not more, not less :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using a callback via an abstract class (interface), and using `std::function` have each advantages and disadvantages. It's also a matter of opinion and preference.

Having said that, I'll try to demonstrate 2 extreme cases where I believe it is better suited to use this or the other.

**Using an interface:**

The main advantage of using an interface, is that you can have all the callback in one place. If you some server class with some methods (the incoming interface), it's convenient to think of the callbacks (where the server notifies of certain events) as an out going interface and treat them as one entity. It also allows, with the usage of pure virtual methods, to force the client to implement them (and therefore be aware of the various notifications).

Typical example:

```
struct SomeServerCallback
{
    virtual void NotifyX() = 0;
    virtual void NotifyY() = 0;
    virtual void NotifyZ() = 0;
    // ...
};

class SomeServer
{
public:
    SomeServer(SomeServerCallback * pCallback) : m_pCallback(pCallback) {}
    void Do1() { /*...*/ }
    void Do2() { /*...*/ }
    // ...
protected:
    SomeServerCallback * m_pCallback;
};
```

**Using a `std::function`:**

On the other hand, if you have another server class that does not need to notify the client of various events, but does need a callback for printing messages, it can be more convenient to use `std::function`, rather then define an interface and force clients to derive from it. It allows the client to choose how to define the callback (using a lambda, `std::bind` with a class method etc.).

Typical example for this case:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class SomeOtherServer
{
public:
    using MyPrintCallback = std::function<void(std::string const&)>;
    SomeOtherServer(MyPrintCallback printCallback) : m_printCallback(printCallback) {}
    void Do1() { /*...*/ }
    void Do2() { /*...*/ }
    // ...
protected:
    MyPrintCallback m_printCallback;
};
```

Using these solutions involves different overheads (performance-wise and others).
But I believe none of them is in principle prefered over the other.